# FSB: Translating MT/s to MHz

Tags: motherboard, fsb

When comparing a few motherboards, I noticed that some have their FSBs listed in MHz (as usual) but a few others have them listed in MT/s. Is there an easy way to convert or translate the value in MT/s to MHz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most motherboard listings have already multiplied the actual frequency by the number of operations per clock to give number of transfers per second, they just leave it labeled as MHz.  If you are in doubt you can always look up the socket on Wikipedia and it will show the values in MT/s.  [LGA 775](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) for example.

Comment: So I was comparing the ASUS A8N-LA and the ASUS A8N-VM, both Socket 939. The A8N-VM has a 1000 MHz FSB, but the A8N-LA has a 2000 MT/s FSB. I'm still not too sure where I'm supposed to look...

Comment: Yeah it looks like Wikipedia doesn't have the 939 labeled in MT/s, both those boards have a 2000MT/s HyperTransport link to the CPU.

Comment: So I'm guessing since the one board has a 1000 MHz FSB... the other one does as well...

Comment: Yeah they are the same.  For HyperTransport and Intel Quickpath Interrupt boards the MT/s should be double the MHz.  For older boards it is a little more confusing because they will both the effective and actual FSB speeds are labeled MHz, but most Intel boards had a quad data rate and most AMDs were double data rate.